# psql asks for password despite configuring trust authentication from localhost

Tags: postgresql, centos6, psql

In `/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/pg_hba.conf`, I have the following:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

But when I execute

```
su -c "psql -d postgres" - postgres
```

it asks me for a password. My expectation is that users should **not** be prompted for a password.

Comment: If you don't specify a host through [`-h`/`--host`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) then `psql` will (try to) connect through Unix-domain socket. Which is type `local` in the [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Comment: If you are on MacOS local socket connections will be made via IPv6 by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were other settings in there for local and IPv6 connections which were not `trust`. I made them all `trust` and it works now. So it looks like psql doesn't connect via IPv4.

Comment: Or if there are 127.0.0.1 rules and localhost rules, then it might not have been using the one you expected.

Answer (score 0):

The address of the record with the trust field in the pg_hba.conf file needs to be ::1/128, presumably because the PostgreSQL server running on your local machine is using an address in that range.